# Infinite build process

Tags: github, yaml, vuejs3, vue-cli, npm-build

I trying to deploy my project.It always worked correct, but now it takes a lot of time for building app and don't end building.I didn't change nothing.
1)this is the log from GitHub
2023-10-03T18:43:45.9941224Z Requested labels: ubuntu-latest
2023-10-03T18:43:45.99415657 Job defined at: myRepo/directory/ github/workflows/main-yml@refs/heads/main
2023-10-03T18:43:45.9941674Z Waiting for a runner to pick up this job...
2023-10-03T18:43:46.9408124Z Job is waiting for a hosted runner to come online.
2023-10-0371:43:49.71578372 Job is about to start running on the hosted runner: GitHub Actions 1 (hosted)
2)This is log of process
Run npm run build

frontend@0.1.0 build
vue-cli-service build
All browser targets in the browserslist configuration have supported ES module.
Therefore we don't build two separate bundles for differential loading.

Building for production... (edited)
Guidelines
I have read the above statement and can confirm my post is relevant to the GitHub feature areas Issues and/or Projects.
This is my main.yml
`
name: FTP Deploy

on:
push:
branches:
- main  # Adjust to your main branch name

jobs:
deploy:
runs-on: ubuntu-latest

```
steps:
  - name: Checkout Repository
    uses: actions/checkout@v3

  - name: Install dependencies
    run: npm install
    working-directory: frontend

  - name: Build Vue.js app
    run: npm run build -- --verbose
    working-directory: frontend

  - name: frontend
    uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@v4.3.4

    with:
      server: ${{ secrets.FTP_SERVER }}
      username: ${{ secrets.FTP_FRONT_USER }}
      password: ${{ secrets.FTP_FRONT_PASSWORD }}
      local-dir: ./frontend/dist/
      remote-dir: /

  - name: backend
    uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@v4.3.4
    with:
      server: ${{ secrets.FTP_SERVER }}
      username: ${{ secrets.FTP_BACK_USER }}
      password: ${{ secrets.FTP_BACK_PASSWORD }}
      local-dir: ./backend/
      remote-dir: /`
```

I try to build local and it works.